# How can I read a file in Java

Tags: java, file, null, syntax-error, ioexception

I am creating a program in Java and I want to read a file named "medicos.txt." After reading the file I want to save all the information. The problem is that when the program starts reading the file, I don't know why it goes to another function in the middle of the function. Here is my code:

```
List<Zona> listaZonas;
final String NOMBRE_FICHERO = "files/medicos.txt";
final String NOMBRE_FICHERO_DAT = "files/medicos2.dat";

public FicheroZonas() {
    listaZonas = leerClaseFichero();
    // leerClaseFichero();
}

public List<Zona> getListaZonas() {
    return listaZonas;
}

public List<Zona> leerClaseFichero() {
    String linea = " ";
    listaZonas = new ArrayList<>();
    Zona zona = null;

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NOMBRE_FICHERO))) {

        while ((linea = in.readLine()) != null) {
            zona = leerZona(linea);

            if (zona != null) {
                listaZonas.add(zona);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al leer el fichero");
    }
    return listaZonas;
}

private Zona leerZona(String linea) {
    String[] zonas = linea.split("[$]");
    List<Medico> listaMedicos = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] strMedicos = zonas[2].split("[%]");

    for (int i = 0; i < strMedicos.length; i++) {
        String datos[] = strMedicos[i].split("[&]");
        Medico medico = new Medico(datos[0], datos[1], datos[2]);
        listaMedicos.add(medico);
    }
    Zona zona = new Zona(zonas[0], listaMedicos);

    return zona;
}
```

In that code, after doing `String[] strMedicos = zonas[2].split("[%]");` it goes to
`catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Error al leer el fichero"); }` and it doesn't do the `for`.

After that when I want to do this:

```
ficheroZonas = new FicheroZonas();

listaZonas = ficheroZonas.getListaZonas();

lZonas = new JList<>();
        
for (int i = 0; i < listaZonas.size(); i++) {
    modeloZona.add(i, listaZonas.get(i));
}
```

I can't do it because `listaZonas` is null. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a `NullPointerException` I strongly recommend to initialize the `listaZonas` like

```
List<Zona> listaZonas = Collections.emptyList();
```

The `IOException` has nothing to do with `String[] strMedicos = zonas[2].split("[%]");`. Because `%` is no special character `split("%")` is sufficient.
Neither it is a `FileNotFoundException` if `Error al leer el fichero` was printed.
I'ld guess Your file is empty or read-protected.